# error while accessing msaccess database via lan in c# application

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, corrupt

I have created a `C#` windows application. When I run it on my local computer it runs successfully - however when I run it on the client computer and try to update records of a `ms-access` database (stored on server computer) using map drive, it shows this error:

> Cannot open database. It may not be a database that your application recognises, or the file may be corrupt.

It shows this error while I am trying to update lots of records in a loop.

Regards

Comment: Can you post some code? Maybe the loop that you are using to update records.

Comment: Can you post connection string used and Windows OS version along with CPU type (32 bit or 64bit). Are they different from your local machine?

Comment: Try Tools > Database Utilities > Compact and Repair database on your local machine and then see if it is accessible from client computer

Comment: @Swemoph
Code is this: for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    dou_totalMarks = mainob.get_cmdScalerValue(str_command + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["schno"].Value.ToString());
                    str_remarks = mainob.get_remarks5Sscale(dou_totalMarks, "EVS2", comboBox3.Text);
                    con.Open();
                    cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("update command", con);
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    progressBar1.Increment(1);
                }

Comment: @ManishDalal 
Connection string
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=" ";Persist Security Info=True;Jet OleDb:Database Password=XXXXXXX;
OS: Windows 7 CPU Both 32 bit or 64 bit

Comment: Why have you kept Data Source blank? Data Source should contain path to the file like Data Source="C:\myFolder\myFile.mdb"

Comment: @ManishDalal that is not blank there is path of my database .mdb file.

Answer (score 0):

It may happen that you are using a newer version of MS Access on your machine and your client is running an older version of MS Access.

Comment: My application is using older version i.e. .mdb file but on machine it is windows 7 and windows 10 with MS access 2007 and 2013 respectively.